# Error installing mrjob on Mac (OS X 10.11.1)

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, osx-elcapitan, mrjob

Typing in Terminal

> pip install mrjob

gives the error message: "NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined" and "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private..."

Using

> sudo pip install mrjob

also gives the same error message.  In addition, it gives this message:

> Password: The directory '/Users/.../Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.  The directory '/Users/.../Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

How do I successfully install?

Comment: I couldn't replicate on OsX 10.11.1 =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between [March 2015](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/pull/973) and [May](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/pull/1007) 2015, the `mrjob` `setup.py` used the Python-2 only built-in function [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile), which was removed from the [Python 3 built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

The `NameError` you encountered strongly suggests that the problem was due to using the Python 3 interpreter.

The project had a [similar bug](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/issues/1124#issuecomment-138605770) raised in September 2015, and the fixed `setup.py` had not yet been released at that time.  It appears that this bug was fixed in [v0.5.0](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/releases/tag/v0.5.0), released 28 March 2016.

To install, use a version criteria:

```
pip install --user "mrjob>=5"
```

Also probably upgrading pip might solve the problems you mention wrt `sudo`, but that seems like an unrelated problem best addressed in a separate question.

Comment: I believe that I had updated my Python interpreter to Python 3 before I attempted this install. Thanks!